# OS Error: Access is denied. , errno = 5 in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-web

`Target debug_android_application failed: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to 'C:\Users\TITYA\flutter_udemy_four\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\assets\food.jpg', path = 'C:\Users\TITYA\flutter_udemy_four\assets\food.jpg' (OS Error: Access is denied.
, errno = 5)

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank`

Answer (score 0):

Run the command you are using in as an admin terminal